# How do I automatically specify the correct regression model when the number of variables differs between input data sets?

Tags: r, automation, regression, nonlinear-functions

I have a working `R` program that will be used by my internal client for analysing their nutrient intake data. For each dataset that they have, they will re-run the `R` program.

A key part of the dataset is an nonlinear mixed method analysis, using `nlmer` from the `lme4` package, that incorporates dummy variables for age. Depending on whether they will be analysing children or adults, the number of age band dummies in the formula will differ, although the reference age band dummy will always be the youngest. I think that the number of possible age bands ranges from 4 to about 6, so it's not a large range. It is a trivial matter to count the number of age band dummies, if I need to condition based on that.

What is the most efficient way for me to wrap the model-based code (the `lmer` that provides the starting parameter values, the function for the `nlmer` model, and the  model specification in `nlmer` itself) so that the correct function and models are applied based on the number of age band dummies in the model? The other variables in the model are constant across datasets.

I've already got the program set up for automatically generating the relevant dummies and dropping those that aren't used in the current analysis. The program after the model is pretty well set up as automated as well. I'm just stuck on what to do with automating the two `lme4`-based analyses and function. These will only be run once for each dataset.

I've been wondering whether I need to write a function to contain all the `lme4` related code, or whether there was an easier way. I would appreciate some pointers on how to do this. It took me one day to work out how to get the function working that I needed for the `nlmer` model, so I am still at a beginner level with functions.

I've searched for other `R` related automation questions on the site and I didn't find anything similar to what I would like to do.

Thanks in advance.

Update in response to suggestion in the comments about using a string. That sounds like an easy way forward for me, except that I don't then know how to apply the string content in a function as each dummy variable level (excluding the reference category) is used in the function for `nlmer`. How can I pull apart the string and use only the dummy variables that I have in a function? For example, one analysis might have AgeBand2, AgeBand3, AgeBand4, and another analysis might have AgeBand5 as well as those 3? If this was `VBA`, I would just create subfunctions based on the number of age dummy variables. I have no idea how to do this efficiently in `R`.

Can I just wrap a `while` loop around the `lmer`, function, and `nlmer` parts, so I have a series of `while` loops?

This is the section of code I wish to automate, the number of AgeBand dummy variables differs depending on the dataset that will be analysed (children vs. adults). This is using the dataset that I have been testing a `SAS` to `R` translation on, but the real datasets will be very similar. It is necessary to have a nonlinear model as this is the basis of the peer-reviewed published method that I am working off.

```
library(lme4)
Male.lmer <- lmer(BoxCoxXY ~ AgeBand4 + AgeBand5 + AgeBand6 + AgeBand7 +
        AgeBand8 + Race1 + Race3 + Weekend + IntakeDay + (1|RespondentID),
    data=Male.AddSugar,
    weights=Replicates)

Male.lmer.fixef <- fixef(Male.lmer)
Male.lmer.fixef <- as.data.frame(Male.lmer.fixef)
bA <- Male.lmer.fixef[1,1]
bB <- Male.lmer.fixef[2,1]
bC <- Male.lmer.fixef[3,1]
bD <- Male.lmer.fixef[4,1]
bE <- Male.lmer.fixef[5,1]
bF <- Male.lmer.fixef[6,1]
bG <- Male.lmer.fixef[7,1]
bH <- Male.lmer.fixef[8,1]
bI <- Male.lmer.fixef[9,1]
bJ <- Male.lmer.fixef[10,1]

MD <- deriv(expression(b0 + b1*AgeBand4 + b2*AgeBand5 + b3*AgeBand6 + 
    b4*AgeBand7 + b5*AgeBand8 + b6*Race1 + b7*Race3 + b8*Weekend + b9*IntakeDay),
namevec=c("b0","b1","b2","b3", "b4", "b5", "b6", "b7", "b8", "b9"),
function.arg=c("b0","b1","b2","b3", "b4", "b5", "b6", "b7", "b8", "b9",
               "AgeBand4","AgeBand5","AgeBand6","AgeBand7","AgeBand8",
               "Race1","Race3","Weekend","IntakeDay"))

Male.nlmer <- nlmer(BoxCoxXY ~ MD(b0,b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9,AgeBand4,AgeBand5,AgeBand6,AgeBand7,AgeBand8,
 Race1,Race3,Weekend,IntakeDay)
    ~ b0|RespondentID,
    data=Male.AddSugar,
    start=c(b0=bA, b1=bB, b2=bC, b3=bD, b4=bE, b5=bF, b6=bG, b7=bH, b8=bI, b9=bJ),
        weights=Replicates
        )
```

These will be the required changes between the datasets:

1. the number of fixed effect coefficients that I need to assign out of the `lmer` will change.
2. in the function, the expression, name.vec, and function.arg parts will change
3. the `nlmer`, the model statement and start parameter list will change.

I can change the `lmer` model statement so it takes AgeBand as a factor with levels, but I still need to pull out the values of the coefficients afterwards.

`str(Male.AddSugar)` gives:

```
'data.frame':   10287 obs. of  23 variables:
$ RespondentID: int  9966 9967 9970 9972 9974 9976 9978 9979 9982 9993 ...
$ RACE        : int  2 3 2 2 3 2 2 2 2 1 ...
$ RNDW        : int  26290 7237 10067 75391 1133 31298 20718 23908 7905 1091 ...
$ Replicates  : num  41067 2322 17434 21723 375 ...
$ DRXTNUMF    : int  27 11 13 18 17 13 13 19 11 11 ...
$ DRDDAYCD    : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ IntakeAmt   : num  33.45 2.53 9.58 43.34 55.66 ...
$ RIAGENDR    : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ RIDAGEYR    : int  39 23 16 44 13 36 16 60 13 16 ...
$ Subgroup    : Ord.factor w/ 6 levels "3"<"4"<"5"<"6"<..: 4 3 2 4 1 4 2 5 1 2 ...
$ WKEND       : int  1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 ...
$ AmtInd      : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ IntakeDay   : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ Weekend     : int  1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 ...
$ Race1       : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 ...
$ Race3       : num  0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ AgeBand4    : num  0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 ...
$ AgeBand5    : num  0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ AgeBand6    : num  1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 ...
$ AgeBand7    : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 ...
$ AgeBand8    : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ YN          : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ BoxCoxXY    : num  7.68 1.13 3.67 8.79 9.98 ...
```

The AgeBand data is incorrectly shown as the ordered factor `Subgroup`. Because I haven't used it, I haven't gone back and correct this to a plain factor.

Comment: What is the criteria for "Correct" model? If you are using some metrics perhaps something similar to an information criterion would help, where you get a trade-off between "fitting" or improved likelihood and the number of parameters.

Comment: The correct model is based on theory, so there is no adjustment to the model on the basis of coefficient size, etc. The adjustments are just on the basis of the number of age bands, and therefore age band dummies, in the data set, and this varies between data sets but is known once the data set is read in and set up for analysis.

Comment: I read the question again and from what I understood it seems like you have to call some objects generated by nlmer. Am I right? you could start by applying str() to the object and also names() so you could have an idea of where the objects of your interest are located. I think the lm type functions save the model as an object.

Comment: The issue is the model specification in `nlmer` and `lmer`, and the function for the model in `nlmer` differs on the basis of how many age groups are being analysed. I want to run the same `R` code across multiple datasets, so I don't know how to automate those processes in R based on varying numbers of age band dummy variables.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are trying to automate: 
is it the formula describing the model, because the number of variables changes?
You rarely have to create dummy variables yourself: 
if it is a factor, R will silently create the dummy variables.
The formula describing the model can be for the form `y~.`, 
meaning "regress y against all other variables" 
or `y~.-x3`, meaning "regress y against all other variables except x3".
This should work for mixed models as well,
but for non-linear models,
it may be easier to build the formula as a string 
and convert it with `as.formula`.

Comment: @VincentZoonekynd in `nlmer` I have specified the dummy variables individually because the model requires them to be related to the model parameters, and I couldn't work out how to do that by using a factor-based approach rather than a dummy variable-based approach.

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that you have one variable, "ageband",  which is a factor with levels: AgeBand2, AgeBand3, AgeBand4, and perhaps others that you want to be ignored.  Since factors are generally treated by R regression functions using the lowest lexigraphic values  as the reference levels, you would get your correct level chosen automagically.  You pick your desired levels by creating a dataset hat has only the desired levels.

```
agelevs <- c("AgeBand2", "AgeBand3", "AgeBand4")
dsub <- subset(inpdat, ageband %in agelevs)
res <- your_fun(dsub) nlmer(y ~ ageband + <other-parameters>, data=dsub, ...)
```

If you have gone to the trouble of creating separate variables, then you need to learn to use factors correctly rather than holding to inefficent habits enforced by training in SPSS or other clunky macro processors.

Comment: In the `nlmer`, each level of AgeBand excluding the reference category has a different starting parameter supplied for the beta. I didn't use a single factor because the betas are different for each AgeBand level.

Comment: Accepting for purposes of argument that this is correct (although I doubt its truth) , you need to provide a less vague description of your data arrangement. At the very least str() on the dataframe but even better would be dput() on a small subset.